# Conformal mapping between disk and the complement of a spiral

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

The Riemann mapping theorem guarantees the existence of a biholomorphic mapping between the unit disk and the complement in the complex plane of an (archimedean or logarithmic) spiral ... is it known an explicit formula for such a map? Anyone knows something about such functions and can provide me any reference?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For anyone interested in the answer, a conformal map that do the job should be $f(z)=(i(1-z)/(1+z))^{2(1+i/λ)}$, where $\lambda>0$ is the parameter of the logarithmic spiral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A hint:

Given a $\lambda>0$ the function
$$f(z):=e^{(\lambda+i)z}$$
maps the strip $0< {\rm Im}(z)<{2\pi\over\lambda}$ conformally onto the complement of the logarithmic spiral with polar representation $r(\phi)=e^{\lambda\phi}$ $\ (-\infty<\phi<\infty$).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the illuminating answer :)